# Displaying the numeric keypad in Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-5, keypad

I need to display the numeric keypad in Windows 10 using Delphi 5.

I tried to just execute `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe` but the problem is that I can't set the default to the numberpad because it always opens the full keyboard.

I tried to set `KeyboardLayoutPreference` to `1` in the registry as suggested in other answers, but that doesn't do anything good either.

Comment: I clearly noted that I tried the solution in the other question and it does not work for me.

Comment: Nonetheless, the question is the same. You can comment on the answers indicating that they didn't work. You can offer a bounty on the other questions if you require additional answers. Nothing about the question is Delphi-specific.

Comment: It is Delphi specific, I don't really want to use the built in keyboard, a delphi component that offers a onscreen keyboard is even better. XE7 has such a component but I couldn't install it on Delphi5

Comment: If your question is Delphi-specific, then [edit] the question to present that new information. As of now, the question you asked is about how to run an external program in a particular mode, which is a question that has been asked on Stack Overflow multiple times before.

Comment: I want to leave it open for any option that might work, I don't want to limit it to delphi.

Comment: Option that might work to resolve *what new problem*, though? What is your unique question that hasn't been asked and answered here before, Ezi? [Edit] your question to make that clear.